# Java how do you deobfuscatate shift and & values?

Tags: java, bit-shift, deobfuscation

Lets say I got this for example (from java obfuscation) with a highly overflowed shift value

```
x = buffer[count + -3] << 0x8f553768 & 0xff00
```

From trying I figured this out..

8 =  0x ff 00

16 = 0x ff 00 00

24 = 0x ff 00 00 00

pretty much I am deobfuscatating to look like this.

```
x = ((buffer[coint - 3] << 8) & 0xff)
```

I got most of it working like flipping the `[+ -]` to `[- +]` all this is easy to fix..
But these shifts are really giving me a hard time.

I found a technique of using AND on the value like
`0x8f553768 & 31` which gives the proper answer of `8` etc..
Then I would convert `0xff00` to the equivalent of unsigned byte.. which is `0xff`

My question is how do I lower the bitmasks to it's proper values.. say this example

```
i1 << 0xf7c13d2a & 0xfc00      //Aka 0xf7c13d2a & 31 == 10
```

which I got down to..

```
i1 << 10 & 0xfc00
```

how do I lower the `0xfc00` to it's proper value?

I took a `guess` should look like this

```
i1 << 10 & 0x3f
```

but whats the formula to lower `AND` values?

Comment: As always you ask wierd questions ;)

Comment: haha eng.fouad always lurking around here too :P, I want to complete this project so badly!, it'll remove all the commercial obfuscations from java apps (hopefully :P)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha solved my brain did the calculation in its head..

damn why do answers come so hard for me..

`i1 << 10 & 0xfc00`

then you do

`0xfc00 >> 10` which gives you `0x3f`

Comment: I think it took you longer to write the question than it did to solve it.

Comment: That it did, I always know the answer.. but my brain got issues at seeking the information it contains. (I just hope this is flawless and won't have some unexpected behavior like all my own solutions always have some downfalls somewhere haha)